# Ring of formal power series over $\mathbb{R}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, formal-power-series

I am studying ring of formal power series over $\mathbb{R}$ and trying to solve this following exercise.

The ring of formal power series over $\mathbb{R}$, denoted $\mathbb{R} [[ x ]]$, is a ring whose elements are power series $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots$ with each $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$, without regard to whether or not such series converge or eventually terminate.  The addition and multiplication of series is defined in the natural way.

> Is there any not invertible element in $\mathbb{R} [[ x ]]$?
>
> Is any unit of $\mathbb{R} [[ x ]]$ is of form $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i$ where $a_i$ are invertible in $\mathbb{R}$?

If this is true, then all the element in $\mathbb{R} [[ x ]]$ is true since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field.

> Is $\mathbb{R} [[ x ]]$ is a local ring?

To prove $\mathbb{R} [[ x ]]$ is a local ring, I need to prove that there is a unique maximal ideal. However I am unable to find one as of now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $x$ invertible? Which $a_i$ are not invertible in $\mathbb{R}$? What characterizations of local rings do you know?

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1 : take an invertible element $A=\sum_{i\geqslant 0} a_i X^i$, and let $B=\sum_{i\geqslant 0} b_i X^i$ be the multiplicative inverse of $A$. One has
$1 = AB = \sum_{i\geqslant 0} \big( \sum_{k=0}^i a_k b_{i-k} \big) X^i$. Compare termwise, eg you get $a_0b_0=1$, $a_0b_1 + a_1 b_0=0$ ...

Hint 2 : a ring is local iff the set of all non-invertible elements forms an ideal.